# Inline function definition with external linkage containing reference to a static object

Tags: c, language-lawyer, inline-functions

There is a constraint `6.7.4(p3)`:

> An inline definition of a function with external linkage shall not
>   contain a definition of a modifiable object with static or thread
>   storage duration, and shall not contain a reference to an identifier
>   with internal linkage.

Consider the following example:

```
static const int i = 10;

void do_print(void);

inline void do_print(void){
    printf("%d/n", i); //Reference to an identifier with internal linkage
                       //constraint violation
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d522396e699bc11)

Here the inline definition of a function with external linkage uses an identifier with internal linkage. So according to `5.1.1.3(p1)`:

> A conforming implementation ***shall produce at least one diagnostic***
>   ***message*** (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a
>   preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a
>   violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is
>   also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined.

I expected the violation of this constraint is reported by the compiler somehow (some warning). But the code compiles just fine with no warnings or some other message produced.

***The question is***: Why is no diagnostic message produced in case of the constraint violation above?

Comment: I would say: Because `i` is a constant, so it is effectively treated as `printf("%d\n", 10);` anyway. Going after the word of the standard, a diagnostic message should be produced, but why should gcc follow that, if it's completely senseless?

Comment: To dig deeper into that: What is the sense of this anyway: "shall not contain a reference to an identifier with internal linkage.". I currently fail to see, why that should be?

Comment: @Ctx So with gcc such reference within inline definition can be considered a well-defined behavior?

Comment: Apple LLVM 10.0.1 with clang-1001.0.46.3 warns with `-pedantic`: “warning: static variable 'i' is used in an inline function with
      external linkage [-Wstatic-in-inline]”.

Comment: GCC has a bug. Nothing more to it. Clang reports it

Comment: @Ctx: GCC does not complain even when `const` is removed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Can you see why this constraint exists anyway?

Comment: @Ctx - If one TU has an external definition for that function, it will use the static for that TU. Whereas the inline definitions will use the static that is local to the TU they appear in. Since it's unspecified whether the implementation uses the inline definition or the external definition of the function, this can lead to problematic code. And such is UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller since the `inline void do_print(void)` only exists in one TU, this is not an issue. It would only be an issue, if this was inside an include file, which is multiply included in different TUs, which cannot be, since do_print has external linkage

Comment: @Ctx - Which is the general case. The header may also include `static` variables. And `do_print` here had no linkage.

Comment: @StoryTeller Then `do_print()` had to have internal linkage

Comment: @Ctx - I suggest you read [this](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9) and [this](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2) once over. The committee's rationale should become apparent then, even if you still do not agree with their choice in dealing with the issues.

Comment: @Ctx: The standard explicitly permits an *inline definition* on one translation unit and an external definition in another translation unit. (An *inline definition* is a definition using `inline` while no file-scope declaration in the translation unit has `extern` or does not have `inline`.) And it says “An inline definition provides an alternative to an external definition, which a translator may use to implement any call to the function in the same translation unit. It is unspecified whether a call to the function uses the inline definition or the external definition.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Just tried it... `void do_print(void);` in one TU and `inline void do_print(void);` in another one. Error: multiple definitions. Another gcc bug?

Comment: @SomeName As I said, if you have `inline void do_print() { ...}` in one TU, there is an external definition with gcc, so no external do_print() can exist in another TU.

Comment: @Ctx: Yes, I think that is a GCC bug. C 2018 6.7.4 7 says “An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function, and does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's quite a big non-conformance, I think. "Somebody" should report it. So `inline void do_print() ...` is basically the same as `static inline void do_print() ...`, correct? That was new to me...

Comment: Almost, but not quite, @Ctx.  With `inline void do_print()`, the calls to the function may use an external definition from another TU.  With `static inline void do_print()`, calls will always use the internal definition.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The case if one TU provides an inline definition and another TU provides an external definition of the same function looks a bit artificial to me. In case the function is declared in a header file as non-inline and then is included into different `c` files we have no inline definition in any TU.

Comment: Perhaps such a configuration is unlikely, @SomeName, but the point is that `inline void f()` is not (quite) semantically equivalent to `static inline void f()`.  Another difference would be that the former can be made to provide an external definition by including another declaration of the function in the same TU that explicitly declares it `extern`.  Best practice is probably to avoid the mess altogether by using `inline` only for functions with internal linkage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **The question is**: Why is no diagnostic message produced in case of the constraint violation above?

Because your compiler is non-conforming in this regard.

That's really all there is to it.  You have analyzed the text of the standard correctly, and applied it correctly to the code presented.  A conforming implementation must emit a diagnostic about the reference to variable `i` by the inline implementation of `do_print`.  An implementation that does not is, ergo, non-conforming.

I note at this point that some compilers are non-conforming in this general way -- omitting required diagnostics -- by default, while providing an option for turning on these mandatory diagnostics.  This is the function of the `-pedantic` option in GCC, for example.  However, I find that my (somewhat dated) version of GCC does not warn about your code even when `-pedantic` is specified.

Answer (score 4):

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline) has a paragraph that explains the rationale behind that:

> If a function is declared inline in some translation units, it does not need to be declared inline everywhere: at most one translation unit may also provide a regular, non-inline non-static function, or a function declared extern inline. This one translation unit is said to provide the external definition. One external definition must exist in the program if the name of the function with external linkage is used in an expression, see one definition rule.
>
> If the external definition exists in the program, the address of the function is always the address of the external function, but when this address is used to make a function call, it's unspecified whether the inline definition (if present in the translation unit) or the external definition is called.

A note also says (emphasize mine):

> The inline keyword was adopted from C++, but in C++, if a function is declared inline, it must be declared inline in every translation unit, and also every definition of an inline function must be exactly the same (**in C, the definitions may be different, as long as the behavior of the program does not depend on the differences**). On the other hand, C++ allows non-const function-local statics and all function-local statics from different definitions of an inline function are the same in C++ but distinct in C.

That means that if a local inline function uses a `static const value` in one translation unit, a non inline function with same name could be defined in a different translation unit with a different value for the static const variable, leading to explicit UB because it is unspecified whether the compiler will use the local inline of the global non inline version.